# How to count the number of rows in an Excel table using excel

Tags: excel

I'd like to reliably count the number of rows in a given excel table using excel formulas.

The rough equivalent of:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").Rows.Count
```

Using built-in Excel formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non-volatile count of the rows in the table including the headers,

```
=ROWS(INDEX(Table1[#All], 0, 1))
```

For the rows in the .DataBodyRange without the header row,

```
=ROWS(INDEX(Table1, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found a nice solution while researching this question:

```
=ROWS(INDIRECT("Table1"))
```

Feel free to post other options!